# How to write to a file and leave an empty line every two records?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.7
I have a list with cities and i want to write them in a text file. Is there a way I can leave an empty line every two cities?

For example:

```
listc=[London,Rome,Moscow,Paris]
nfile=open("towns.txt",'w')
for line in nfile:
    for town in listc:
        if line%2==0:
            nfile.write(town+'\n')
        else:
            nfile.write('\n')
nfile.close()
```

I want to achieve this:

```
London
Rome
\n      # leave an empty line every second city
Moscow
Paris
```

But it's wrong because it skips the cities instead of writing them next.

Comment: What is the code you are using for writing the cities w/o the blank lines?

Comment: Hi, show to us what you've been tried. Provide some code to help us to analyze where are you doing wrong.

Comment: `'\n'` is a newline character.  Add that to your code that `write` or `print`.

Comment: easy change:      if line%2==0:
            nfile.write(town+'\n' + '\n')
        else:
            nfile.write(town+'\n')

Answer (score 6):

You should do something like this:

```
listc=["London", "Rome", "Moscow", "Paris"]
nfile=open("towns.txt", 'w')

i = 0

for town in listc:
       nfile.write(town)
       if i == 2:
           nfile.write('\n')
           i = 0
           continue
       i += 1

nfile.close()
```

---

If you just want to reuse your code, just replace the

```
nfile.write('\n')
```

with

```
nfile.write(town)
```

because that means that if it is not second line, you want to just write "\n" which means empty line => it leaves out the town

Comment: Oh my apologies i skip a part of my code i edited it  again in the question. (i'm new here!)

Comment: NameError: name 'line' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you want to write the name every time and only add an extra line after every other one:

```
listc = ['London', 'Rome', 'Moscow', 'Paris']
nfile = open("towns.txt", 'w')
for line, town in enumerate(listc):
    nfile.write(town + '\n')
    if line % 2 == 1:
        nfile.write('\n')
nfile.close()
```

Comment: My apologies i forgot to put one more piece of the code here i edited the question i think the ''line'' index is wrong in my code.